# How to run BootChess?

Tags: software-installation

I am running Ubuntu 14.10 and I have downloaded [BootChess](http://www.pouet.net/prod.php?which=64962), and I have extracted the contents of the ZIP file into a folder called "BootChess" in my home directory.

But I have been having some trouble getting it to run, I tried at first using the `cd` command to get into the BootChess folder and execute the `.bin` file with `./BootChess`, but that outputted the following error:

```
bash: ./BootChess.bin: Permission denied
```

So then I tried changing the permission of that `.bin` file from `-rw-rw-r--`, to `-rwxrwxr-x`.

But when executing the `.bin` file I still get an error (although it is a different error, it is still an error):

```
bash: ./BootChess.bin: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

So now I have run out of ideas and not sure how to proceed to get it working, so that is my question, how can I get BootChess working?

Comment: sounds like you are in a folder that doesn't allow software executions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read file `BootChess.txt` in the archive you downloaded, everything is explained in section "6.1 - FAQ and remaining questions".

Most likely you want to do this:

> -if you have first 487b version (do not change any flags) : x86 equ 1                         ; x86=1 PC/emu vs. win32b/(DOS)Box saf equ 0                         ;
>   saf=0 +queening -exotic failsafe 
>   -if you have second 468b version (change these flags) : gui equ 0           ; gui=1 x86=1 p2q=1 510b+ OK pad OK gui OK vbr- OK queen x86 equ 0
>   ; gui=1 x86=1 p2q=0 498b+ OK pad OK gui OK vbr+ NO queen p2q equ 0
>   ; gui=1 x86=0 p2q=1 504b  NO pad OK gui NO vbr- OK queen to gui equ 1 
>   ; gui=1 x86=1 p2q=1 510b+ OK pad OK gui OK vbr- OK queen x86 equ 1
>   ; gui=1 x86=1 p2q=0 498b+ OK pad OK gui OK vbr+ NO queen p2q equ 1
>   ; gui=1 x86=0 p2q=1 504b  NO pad OK gui NO vbr- OK queen

From `BootChess.txt` in archive:

> Q : How to assemble and test BootChess on real hardware ?    A :
>   download program "fasm" flat assembler 16-bit version
>        1)assemble with "fasm BootChess.asm"
>          make sure preprocessor flag "x86 equ 1" in BootChess.asm
>        2)write physical floppy boot sector as above
>          on Linux type "dd if=BootChess.bin /dev/fd0 bs=512 count=1"
>          on Windows type "partcopy BootChess.bin 0 200 -f0"
>          or type "dd.exe if=BootChess.bin of=\.\a: bs=512 count=1"
>        3)set BIOS boot order 1st Boot Device to "Floppy" and reboot
>        BootChess launches...

And you get this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mlLgOLmQg_g

Enter from keyboard string `H7H5` for example.

Since there are no calls other than BIOS, it ought to run also as 16-bit binary on Linux, but I'm not sure it's been tested.